# Javascript jQuery is it possible to call click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in jquery or javascript to call a button click function. so for example in my JS:

```
$('#right').click(function(){
    //My code
}

//call $('#right').click(function() function here
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with trigger:

```
$('#right').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: hi thanks, that works perfectly, thanks for the link as well to read up on it. Ill mark it when i can.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using **[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** for that.

```
 $('#right').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Directly from the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

> Now if we click on this element, the alert is displayed:
>
> Handler for `.click()` called.
>
> We can also trigger the event when a different element is clicked:
>
> ```
> $( "#other" ).click(function() {
>   $( "#target" ).click();
> });
> ```
>
> After this code executes, clicking on Trigger the handler will also
>   alert the message.

Also in the definition of the function signatures, it also says the third one `.click()` is the same as `.trigger("click")`.